# Sending HTML email in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, html-email

In my project I've added a newsletter feed. But when trying to send emails with this function :

```
def send(request):
    template_html = 'static/newsletter.html'
    template_text = 'static/newsletter.txt'
    newsletters = Newsletter.objects.filter(sent=False)
    subject = _(u"Newsletter")
    adr = NewsletterEmails.objects.all()
    for a in adr:
        for n in newsletters:
            to = a.email
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL           
            subject = _(u"Newsletter Fandrive")
            text = get_template(template_text)
            html = get_template(template_html)
            d = { 'n': n,'email': to }
            text_content = text.render(d)
            html_content = html.render(d)

            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.send()
```

using those templates :

```
//text

===================  Newsletter - {{ n.date }}  ============
==========================================================
                      {{ n.title }}
==========================================================          
{{ n.text }}
==========================================================

//html

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="">
        <div style="">
            <h1 style="">{{ n.title }} - {{n.date}}</h1>
                <p style="">            
                    {{ n.text }}
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and models :

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("title", blank=False, max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField("text", blank=False)
    sent = models.BooleanField("sent", default=False)
    data = models.DateTimeField("creation date", auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

class NewsletterEmails(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(_(u"e-mail address"),)
```

I'm getting :

`TemplateSyntaxError at /utils/newsletter_send/

Caught an exception while rendering: 'dict' object has no attribute 'autoescape'`

in **{{ n.date }}** within text_email template

Although my debug shows I'm sending proper newsletter objects to the template ,as well as debug context :

`context {'email': u'admin@domain.com', 'n': <Newsletter: Newsletter object>}`

Why is that happening ? From what I've found about this error it is somehow connected to sending empty dictionary to template renderer, but mine's not empty...

Comment: in your model definition date field is named as 'data', is that a typo while posting the question or you have it like that in code also ??

Comment: typo, it's date everywhere. Dunno how this could've happened though... :)

Comment: in #django logs I've read 'You're passing a dictionary to something that was expecting a Context object.' . How to solve this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a pretty simple fix, you're missing one minor thing.

You are doing this:

```
  d = { 'n': n,'email': to }
```

Followed by trying to use that dictionary as part of your render() method. However, `render` takes a `Context` so you need to do this:

```
 d = Context({ 'n': n,'email': to })
```

Make sure to import it from `django.template` as well. That should fix the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 19):

Just for informational purpose. I've found another way of doing this :

```
def send(request):
    template_html = 'static/newsletter.html'
    template_text = 'static/newsletter.txt'
    newsletters = Newsletter.objects.filter(sent=False)
    subject = _(u"Newsletter Fandrive")
    adr = NewsletterEmails.objects.all()
    for a in adr:
        for n in newsletters:
            to = a.email
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL           
            subject = _(u"Newsletter Fandrive")

            text_content = render_to_string(template_text, {"title": n.title,"text": n.text, 'date': n.date, 'email': to})
            html_content = render_to_string(template_html, {"title": n.title,"text": n.text, 'date': n.date, 'email': to})

            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.send()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: You left out the import statement of `from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives`

Comment: Is this supposed to send HTML emails or how does this work? I'm trying this approach but I only get the text message

Answer (score 12):

They've updated `send_mail` to allow html messages in the [dev version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/)

```
def send(request):
    template_html = 'static/newsletter.html'
    template_text = 'static/newsletter.txt'
    newsletters = Newsletter.objects.filter(sent=False)
    subject = _(u"Newsletter Fandrive")
    adr = NewsletterEmails.objects.all()
    for a in adr:
        for n in newsletters:
            to = a.email
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL           
            subject = _(u"Newsletter Fandrive")

            text_content = render_to_string(template_text, {"title": n.title,"text": n.text, 'date': n.date, 'email': to})
            html_content = render_to_string(template_html, {"title": n.title,"text": n.text, 'date': n.date, 'email': to})

            send_mail(subject, text_content, from_email,
             to, fail_silently=False, html_message=html_content)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```